# In Cocos2d for iPhone CCSpriteFrameCache takes up lots of Memory

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I am using "Activity monitor" to measure the performance of my App and noticed that the number of sprites I allocate using sprite frames from the CCSpriteFrameCache does really affect the real memory usage of the App.

For example, if I just load a CCSpriteFrameCache with a 2048*2048pixel texture sheet the App has an increase of real memory usage of 16MB. Whenever I allocate even 30 enemy sprites adding the textureatlas.png file to a CCSpriteBatchNode and allocating CCSprites using the frames the real memory has just a very small increase (less than 1MB). **I don't quiet get that.**

I am wondering **how CCSpriteFrameCache works** and **whether I should use sprites files instead of texture atlases to optimize the real memory usage**. Why and how using texture atlases and CCSpriteFrameCache optimizes OpenGL performance? Has anyone found a good article explaining this subject?

Also, in the programming guide there are some suggestion to use PVR format to optimize memory usage (see [link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3abest_practices)) for 2 and 4 bit textures. I have top quality artwork made by an illustrator and if I try to compress it looks rubbish. When is the case that I can consider using **PVR image format**? Are there any good example on this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you running into actual problems because of this memory usage?

Comment: Not too many, but is just that the App real memory usage is about 60MB and I wanted to explore ways to keep it lower than this..

Comment: I kind of get the downvote.. basically I hadn't understood the point of CCSpriteSheets and how those worked (in relation to the OpenGL calls) and also was confused as I thought that each sprite would eat memory space. Thanks to the answer I get more of this so for me has been useful. I hope its not a too bad question, if anyone else will want to downvote could you please also add a comment so I can improve my questions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCSprite instance is just object with set of parameters. One of these parameters is pointer to the texture to use. So, texture is needed to be placed in memory only once. Then Any number of sprites can use it without huge memory usage.

Comment: that's great! So basically CCSprite are initialized either with a reference to a CCTexture2D or to a file within CCTextureCache. I get this. So basically the CCSprite method draws the sprite using the data from the potentially shared texture. Can drawing multiple instances of the same texture (e.g. bullet) affect the framerate? I saw that there are OpenGL calls so I guess that in this case I should worry more about OpenGL performance than memory load, correct?

Comment: PS: I mark the answer as accepted as it answers my original question and I found probably a good guide to the question in my last comment http://allseeing-i.com/Performance-tips-for-Cocos2d-for-iPhone which basically explain why I should use a CCSpriteSheet and how this reduces the number of OpenGL calls and hence improves performance.